# after adding the products, those products are not displaying products page

Tags: magento2, products

Warning: Undefined array key "name" in D:\xampp\htdocs\mage2rock\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions.php on line 61

```
Exception in D:\xampp\htdocs\mage2rock\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:62
```

I am getting this error when products assign to the categories, Those products are not displaying in products page

Answer (score 0):

Please Run Below Commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
Php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You have a product that does not have a name, you can update the name via the database or you can follow the below steps.**

> **Open your vendor file:**

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions.php
```

> **And Update the below code:**

```
/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $storeId = $this->context->getFilterParam('store_id');

        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            if (isset($item['name'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'catalog/product/edit',
                        ['id' => $item['entity_id'], 'store' => $storeId]
                    ),
                    'ariaLabel' => __('Edit ') . $item['name'],
                    'label' => __('Edit'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

Here I only add isset() condition in the exiting code. After you are able to see the grid remove or update the product name. Once the issue is fixed please revert the changes to the above file.

**Please Run Below Commands**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try run indexer command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

or
check the product from admin panel, open product edit page from admin and make sure **visibility** is not set on **Not Visible Individually** if you're adding simple product